# Mutter some .... under one's breath

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction

> Phil and Sam argued last night after the party. I wanted to cool Phil down while he got so mad, but when I was going to walk to him, hr muttered some ....... under his breath at Sam and walked away!

**a. curses** [To me, this choice is the best one. However, I need a native's confirmation on it.] 
**b. curse words** [To me, this is a wordy version of the previous option.] 
**c. obscenities** [It would make the sentence a little stilted in my view.]

Please let me know what is the most natural construction in English to indicate the message in my question.

Comment: Normally, 'Philip' or 'Phillip' are shortened to 'Phil' (one 'L').

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @Michael Harvey. I edited my post.

Answer (score 3):

All three options seem reasonable. I rarely use the noun *curse* by itself when referring to swearing: I think of a *curse* as something you say when you want a divine entity or an evil spirit to harm someone (or the result thereof).

I would personally use the term **obscenities** in this context. I agree that "curse words" is a bit too wordy, though potentially my choice is too formal. Perhaps others have a differing opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The implication is that what was said would have been insulting or provocative if heard, but, because it was not heard, what exactly was said is **DELIBERATIVELY** left vague.

Comment: I'm not following you @Jeff Morrow. Could you please clarify your intention a little more?

Comment: If what was uttered was not provocative, it would almost certainly have been said loud enough to be audible. The fact that it was muttered so as to be inaudible means that we cannot know what was said. It may have been a curse, an obscenity, or a threat. Trying to specify what it was is admitted to be impossible. “I’ll murder you” is not obscene or blasphemous. If you do not want to be prosecuted, it is best not to be audible about threats to murder.